# eclipse hibernate tomcat error

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, tomcat, servlets

I get this error trying to run web app on tomcat in eclipse:

> SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Kartoteka
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1149)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

It seems that there's no specific library but I have no idea which exactly. I use last hibernate version(4.1.8 final). I've tried to link all libraries from hiberante but it doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The JAR file(s) with webapp's runtime dependencies have to go in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. The exception which you're facing suggests that this is not the case. So, to fix it all you have just to make sure that the JAR file(s) are been dropped in the right place.

A common beginner's mistake is that they fiddle in the *Build Path* property of the project in order to add runtime dependencies. That's thus wrong. It only adds compile time dependencies. You need to undo every change which you made in there in an attempt to solve this problem, or it may still collide.

Comment: I had added external jars to build-path not realizing this was bad practice. so moved them from build-path to the /WEB-INF/lib when I received a runtime exception complaining of a class not found. However, now each time I run my project I get an exception pointing towards another class not found exception even though it has been downloaded via Maven and sits in the Maven dependencies folder. It's as though the project now only looks within the /WEB-INF/lib for jars and is just ignoring the  Maven dependencies folder? Any idea why this may be?

Comment: @smoggers: If you're building using Maven instead of "plain" Eclipse, then it will take care about filling `/WEB-INF/lib` with desired dependencies during build (and it will use "provided"-scoped dependencies during compile only). In other words, you should not manually place JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib`, but declare them in pom file with the right scope.